# Is it possible to wait on a task from a thread other than the parent thread?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, nunit

I need to wait on a task that I created in the production code from the test code. Is it possible to do that? I am using Nunit framework for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `Task.Wait` from any thread.